# Angular - Error: ngRepeat:dupes Duplicate Key in Repeater

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on a simple todo app that adds task to an existing array of json data. However when I try to add more than one task I get this error: `Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]`. I can't for the life of me figure out what is going wrong. I suspect it might have something to do with the namespace, but after changing names around a few times I still get the same error. If anybody could point me in the right direction I would much appreciate it.

**The HTML Code**

```
<div id="taskComplete" ng-app="taskComplete">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="taskCtrl">

    <div id="taskCompleteHeading"  class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="page-header">
          <h1 class="text-center">TaskComplete <small>An AgularJs App</small></h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="newTaskSubmit">
      <input type="text" ng-model="newTask.title">
      <input type="text" ng-model="newTask.description">
      <button type="button" ng-click="addTask(newTask)">Add Task</button>         
    </div>

    <div class="well">
    <pre>{{newTask | json}}</pre>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="task in activeTasks">
      <h4>{{task.title}}</h4>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATED SOLUTION**

```
<div ng-repeat="task in activeTasks track by $index">
   <h4>{{task.title}}</h4>
</div>
```

**The JAVASCRIPT Code**

```
angular
.module('taskComplete')
    .controller('taskCtrl', function($scope, taskFactory) {

    $scope.activeTasks;

    taskFactory.getTasks().success(function(data) {
        $scope.activeTasks = data;
        console.log($scope.activeTasks);
    }).error(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });

    $scope.newTask = {};

    $scope.addTask = function(newTask) {
        $scope.activeTasks.push(newTask);   
    }


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.addTask = function(newTask) {
        $scope.activeTasks.push(newTask);   
 }
```

Should become

```
$scope.addTask = function(newTask) {
    $scope.activeTasks.push(newTask);   
    $scope.newTask = {};
}
```

The error was caused by the same object being used twice. It is also why changes below were being mirrored by the added task.

Comment: Sorry just read that someone said this already in the comments to the question.

Comment: Hei, yes i did. It was the only solution i could think of. But thank you for confirming it for me, i was not sure if it was a legitimate solution or just a hacky work around.

Comment: No problem, yes it's the correct way.. Because newTask would still be pointing at the same object you added to the array. This means changes made to it are made would be updated in the U.I. and pushing it to the array again would cause the duplicate error because now you twice added the same object reference to the array.

Comment: Oh wow, that does in fact solve my initial problem as well, i removed 'track by $index' and you are correct sir, now i don't get the 'Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]'. The question is then, should i still use 'track by $index' ?

Comment: Track by is how angular links an object to the Dom element. So it can track which elements need adding/removing/moving when the array is modified. By default angular assigns a unique Id to the object (something like $$ref). This is why duplicates are not allowed.. Because the same object would have the same reference and angular wouldn't know which object maps to which element. By putting 'track by $index' you are telling angular to just use its array position to track. it's more useful if the object has a unique Id property already (like from the database)

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
<div ng-repeat="task in activeTasks track by $index">
   <h4>{{task.title}}</h4>
</div>
```

So angular will track your ng-repeat node

Answer (score 2):

Use `track by $index`:

```
ng-repeat="task in activeTasks track by $index"
```

Comment: Hi your suggestion removes the error, but any changes to the the text in the form field is mirrored in the task that have been added. see link: http://taskcomplete.carbonium.no/apptest.html

Comment: are you clicking on the button after altering the input?

Comment: Yes, however after adding '$scope.newTask = {};' to the 'addTask()' function i can clear the object on submit and this seams to solve the problem. But is this the best solution ?

Comment: by 'clear the object' you mean clear the input, right? If thats the case then yes the approach is fine.